# Multi GPU vs GPU cluster

Tags: cuda, cluster-computing, gpu, multi-gpu

I am using cuda programming for the effective and fast computation. and during the study I found that multi gpu and the gpu cluster are the other means for the much further effective calculation but I am confused between these two terms.

What is the actual difference between these two in terms of programming cuda?

Comment: I'm studying Vulkan, and I know Vulkan can utilize multi-gpu computing resources well. But does Vulkan can manipulate GPU clusters well,too?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean a PC with multiple GPUs and many PCs with single GPU (Cluster)

if this is the case, for a multi-GPU PC you can easily use CUDA library itself and if you connect GPUs with a SLI bridge, you will see improvements in performance.

If you want to use a cluster with GPUs, you may use CUDA-Aware MPI. It is combined solution of MPI standard and CUDA library. I suggest you to check this blog post: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/introduction-cuda-aware-mpi/